# how to convert this String into number

Tags: sql

Can you please help to convert this String into number?

$0.01,$0.05*,$0.06??,
i tried some query but i havent got correct result

Comment: Please share what queries you have tried. Also provide sample data stored in DB along with the table structure for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (NUMBER) FROM DUMMY
```